# What is Observed by a Planet in a Region of Spacetime in a Theoretical Universe that has a Mass Density Gradient?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, space-expansion, event-horizon, dark-energy

Planet M exists in a theoretical Universe that is like our Universe in every way except it can contain Large regions of Spacetime that have mass density gradients.

For a specific time, t, Planet M is insolated by its Past Light Cone at that time, i.e. observes effects from gravity only from objects within that Cone. The mass gradient in this region of spacetime is linear: $\rho(x,y,z,t)=\rho_0 + k x$, i.e. the mass density of each disk defined by a specific value of x would be uniform and $=\rho_0 + k x$ , with kD << $\rho_0$, where D is the diameter of Planet M's Past Light Cone.

What would be the net acceleration of this gravity distribution on Planet M?  How would this be observed by Planet M?

Even a link to a recommended website of GR solutions where I could find the answer myself (or any highly recommended learning materials on GR) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you draw a diagram? Note that talking about disks in a light cone actually means a set of concentric spheres at the same time coordinate, which does not sound like what you want. It sounds like you are trying to ask what happens if there is a uniform spatial density gradient like $\rho(x,y,z,t)=\rho_0 + k x$? for some constant $k$.

Comment: Anders Sandberg, you are exactly correct with your equation, $\rho(x,y,z,t)=\rho_0 + k x$. I have edited my question using your simpler and more effective explanation. Thank you.

Comment: Asking about all the effects of the mass distribution might be a bit too broad. I suggest asking for more specific things - the acceleration is a good start. Also note that $k \ll \rho_0$ does not make sense dimensionally.

Comment: Looking at a perfect fluid at rest with x-varying density gives a stress-energy tensor with just the $T_{tt}$ component nonzero (and linear in $x$, with zero second derivative), and if the metric is diagonal with $ds^2=a(x) dt^2 + b(x) dx^2 + c(x) (dy^2+dz^2)$ *lots* of Christoffel symbols and $G_{ij}$ terms are zero: it looks fairly solvable. I assume this must be in the standard literature somewhere?

Comment: Javier, I changed question to only ask for acceleration.  Good suggestion, thank you. Also, if you set x = 0 at Planet M and x = $x_1$ at Past Light Cone due "north", then by k << $\rho_0$, what I mean is k$x_1$ is a small fraction on the order of say 1% of $\rho_0$. The units of constant k would be density/distance.

Comment: So if x was in Gly, the units of constant k would be density/Gly.

Comment: Anders, again your assumptions are exactly correct. I will search for the answer in parallel with hopes that someone with a better knack for finding such material may be able to send me a link.